# How can I create addons for Live Messenger 2011?

Tags: .net, add-in, windows-live-messenger

If I want to develop an addon for WLM 2011, where should I start?

In the past we could [make add-ins using .NET](http://communitiy.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/17/4431.aspx), but [it has been dropped](http://www.winvistatips.com/enable-add-t358555.html) or at least I can't activate.

How does Messenger Plus! Live modify the Windows Live Messenger? How can I develop an application like that? Where may I find documentation for it?

Comment: There isn't a MessengerClient.dll anymore and `AddinFeatureEnabled` has no effect. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WindowsLiveMessengerAddin.aspx?msg=3349551 http://www.winvistatips.com/enable-add-t358555.html

Comment: A addon to automatically uninstall Messenger 2011 would be awesome. 2011 is the most fail product from the Windows Live Essentials team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the documentation you are asking for is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179336.aspx).